# another extremal property of regular polygons

Tags: matrices, plane-geometry, combinatorial-optimization, real-algebraic-geometry, grassmannians

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}\newcommand{\D}[1]{\Delta_{#1}}\newcommand{\set}[1]{\{#1\}}\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{1}}$
In 1984 S.D.Berman, a Soviet mathematician, asked the following minmax question. Let $X$ be a $n \times 2$ real valued matrix. Let $x_i$ denote the $i$-th row of $X$, and let $\D{ij} = \det(x_i,x_j)$ denote the $ij$-minor of $X$. Define
\begin{equation}
  \label{def:E}
  E(X) \equiv \frac{\max_{i<j}\abs{\D{ij}}}{\min_{i<j}\abs{\D{ij}}}
\end{equation}
Find $X$ that minimizes $E$.

My first question states the conjectured solution, Jeopardy-style.
Let $\set{c_i \in \R^2}_{i=1}^{2n}$ be the vertices of a regular $2n$-polygon, centered at $0$, numbered counterclockwise. Let $C \equiv [c_1, \dots, c_n]$ be a row matrix comprised of the first $n$ vertices.

> Is it true that $C$ minimizes $E(X)$?

I can prove it for $n=4,5$ using nothing but the Plucker equations.
In what follows I ask two specialized questions. An affirmative answer to any of them implies the above conjecture for odd $n$.

Let $n=2d+1$ be an odd integer, and let $\D{} \equiv (\D{1}, \dots, \D{n}) \in \R^n$, $\D{s}>1$. Define
\begin{equation}
  R_s(\D{}) = \D{s-1}^{-1}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & \D{s-1} \\
    -\D{s} & 0
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $\D{0} \equiv \D{n}$.

Consider a matrix equation
\begin{equation}
  \tag{GP}\label{GP}
  \prod_{s=1}^n R_s(\D{}) = (-1)^d \E
\end{equation}
where $\E$ is the identity matrix.

Consider the extremal problem of minimizing $E_1(\D{}) \equiv \max_{s}\D{s}$ over $\R^n$ subject to the constraint \eqref{GP} and $\D{s}>1$. Let $\D{}^* \in \R^n$ be an extremal point.

> Is it true that $\D{}^*$ is a constant vector, i.e. $\D{s}^* = \delta$ for some $\delta$?

This question is related to [Chebyshev-like Problem for Plucker Coordinates](https://mathoverflow.net/q/311964/120176) that I asked earlier.

COMMENT. It might appear that \eqref{GP} imposes four scalar equations however only three of them are independent. Indeed, $\det{R_s} = \D{s} \D{s-1}^{-1}$ and
\begin{equation}
  \det \prod_{s=1}^n R_s = \prod_{s=1}^n \D{s} \D{s-1}^{-1} = 1
\end{equation}
One can prove that if $(\D{1}, \dots, \D{n})$ satisfies \eqref{GP} then so does $(\D{n}, \D{1}, \dots, \D{n-1})$ (cyclical symmetry) and $(\D{n}, \dots, \D{1})$ (mirror symmetry).

For my last question consider the locus of \eqref{GP} as an $n-3$ surface in $\R^n$.

> Is it true that any $n-3$ sub-coordinates of $(\D{1}, \dots, \D{n})$ can be used to parametrize the surface (or a connectivity component if the surface is not connected)?

Answer (score 1):

The positive answer to this question is given in https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.00185.